# word meaning "an object that is benefit from some action"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

### I have already known:

I know "beneficiary" means "a **person** that receives help or an advantage from something". And its synonyms are "heir", "inheritor", which are related to heritage.

But I want a word that can describe an object/thing with more general meaning (i.e., not related to heritage)

### A sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used:

"By resolving bugs of this software, its reliability is enhanced" = "The `[word I want]` of resolving bugs of the software is reliability"

Comment: Your own term “benefit” works well in that context.

Comment: True enough, @Lawrence, but that presents reliability *per se* as an improvement.  OP is looking for some word defined as "that thing which is improved", parallel with "beneficiary" as "that person who receives a benefit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is based on the incorrect assumption that *beneficiary* applies only to people or to legal inheritance as a result of death.

The following is one of the senses used by Merriam-Webster to define [**beneficiary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficiary):

> **1** : a person or thing that receives help or an advantage from something : one that benefits from something
>     // The college was a **beneficiary** of the private grant.

Synonyms for this particular sense, as well as words with related grammatical functions, include the following words: *recipient*, *receiver*, *advantaged*, *advantage*, *benefit*, *benefited*, *profited*, *bettered*, *aided*.

---

As such, the example sentence (which I will paraphrase slightly) can still make use of *beneficiary*—as well as the related *benefit*, depending on the specific nuance being conveyed:

> The *beneficiary* of resolving software bugs is reliability.
> The *benefit* of resolving software bugs is reliability.

---

Other example sentences where *beneficiary* is used in the sense of a thing gaining an advantage follow (the emphasis is my own).

From [*Department of Energy: Implementation and Use of Other Transactions Authority Provided in the Energy Policy Act Of 2005*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-zJ_h6xKULkC&pg=PA4&dq=%22beneficiary%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinhYySz9TqAhXJmuAKHVr4D9sQ6AEwUHoECBkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22beneficiary%20of%22&f=false) by Gene Aloise:

> The **beneficiary** of contracts is the federal government.

From [*Licensing Royalty Rates*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6Um5tpn2hlwC&pg=PA320&dq=%22beneficiary%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinhYySz9TqAhXJmuAKHVr4D9sQ6AEwWXoECBAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22beneficiary%20of%22&f=false) by Gregory J. Battersby and Charles W. Grimes:

> Active Video argues that Verizon is not an intended **beneficiary** of the TV Guide agreement, which was a joint development agreement between Active Videos predecessor and TV Guide to produce a specific product.

From [*Nanotechnology: Social Implications II*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CmvMwoqlIJYC&pg=PA68&dq=%22beneficiary%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6mYjM1dTqAhXMnuAKHR9BAAc4ZBDoATAGegQIYRAC#v=onepage&q=%22beneficiary%20of%22&f=false) edited by Mihail C. Roco and William Sims Bainbridge:

> In any case, virtually all models of technological change predict that the main
> **beneficiary** of technological improvements is the most inelastic factor of
> production. In the modern world. where the supply of labor is inelastic relative to
> the supply of capital and where the supply of economically useful natural
> resources has increased as a result of the discovery of new sources of natural
> resources and/or development of substitute resources, this makes labor the main
> **beneficiary** of technological advance.

From [*A History of Cornwall*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=s_t1BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT270&dq=%22beneficiary%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6mYjM1dTqAhXMnuAKHR9BAAc4ZBDoATAZegQIOBAC#v=onepage&q=%22beneficiary%20of%22&f=false) by Morris Bishop:

> In other states their university is the **beneficiary** of the state; here the state is the **beneficiary** of the university!

From [*In Praise of the Beloved Language*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pXyHP9XkHFMC&pg=PA111&dq=%22beneficiary%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6mYjM1dTqAhXMnuAKHR9BAAc4ZBDoATAkegQIRxAC#v=onepage&q=%22beneficiary%20of%22&f=false) by Joshua A. Fishman:

> As the symbol of the conjoint attainment of literacy (cultural refinement and autonomy (cultural independence), the written language is commonly the ultimate intended goal and **beneficiary** of all modernity-oriented corpus planning initiatives. This is not to say that only the written language is the object or **beneficiary** of such planning, but were such a view to be advanced—and it has been—it would be an exaggeration whose point had much to be said for it.